# Fade in and fade out image captions NYT-style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm pretty new to coding and I would like some pointers on how to do these fade in and fade out of the image captions when scrolling the big cover images?

https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2016/10/24/world/asia/living-in-chinas-expanding-deserts.html?_r=0

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they get how far a user has scrolled and then set the opacity of the texts. You can do that like that:

```
text = document.getElementById("theIdOfTheText");
text.style.opacity = someIntValue;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I'm not quite sure what to do with that though. If it's not too much trouble would you mind providing a bit more context?

Comment: That's no problem at all. The `document.getElementById()` selects an HTML element. The `.style.opacity` is the objects opacity attribute in the style attribute. And `someIntValue` is just a variable that the opacity is set to. But I just realized that it ranges von 0 to 1 so it should actually be a float value (0.0 - 1.0).